# two level counting of records in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table kids(
      familyID bigint references a table with families;
      personID bigint references something that contains records with people/kids
)
```

there can be more than one kid for a given family, i.e. siblings. The idea is to count how many families have siblings.

this query:

```
select count(familyID) from kids group by familyID;
```

will produce a result set that displays the total number of kids for each family. So most families will have 1 kid, some 2 kids, etc.

Now the idea is to further count how many families have one kid, how many 2 kids, how many 3 kids, so the result set should look like something like this:

```
kids      count(familyID)
1         44
2         10
3         2
4         1
```

and if you sum count(familyID): 44+11+2+1=total_number_of_families in the db.

i am trying to get there with subqueries, but can't seem to grasp the concept. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with a temp table

```
select kids , count(*) from 
(
  select familyID,  count(*) kids 
  from kids 
   group by familyID ) as t
group by kids
```

Comment: Yep, it's great. Thank you. Just curious, is this the only way solve such problems that involve multiple iterations over the same data set - create subquery?

Comment: This is not the only  way  ..but easy to understand  ...and the is more useful for learn sql potential .. well if my answer i right please mark it as accepted ..